# Create an object dynamically in java

Tags: java

1. Suppose I have this class:

   ```
   public class Person {
      private String name;
      private int age;
      //setters and getters
      ...
   }
   ```
2. The following code is not correct, but I want something similar.

   ```
   String className="Person";
   String att1 = "name";
   String att2 = "age;
   object o = createClassByName(className);
   setValueForAttribute(o,att1,"jack");
   setValueForAttribute(o,att2,21);"
   ```

Comment: [Trial: The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: If you're using Spring, PropertyAccessorFactory will help you set the properties with minimal effort.

Comment: At least add a constructor so that you don't have to use reflection to set the private fields.  Setting private fields by hand via reflection is so "wrong" ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with hashes? 
I think you could use a HashMap, which is a common Hash implementation built into the Java library:

```
HashMap<String,Object> person1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
person1.put("className", "Person");
person1.put("name", "Jack");
person1.put("age", 21);
```

Everytime you want to change the values, do: `person1.put("name", "Jill")`

And to get the values, it's `person1.get("name")`

If you want to take the class into account, you'll have to get the `className` and manually compare it in your code, to do different things according to the "class" of the object (which in reality is a HashMap, but nevermind).

Small reminder: doing things this way is considered *very* messy ;)